# Form a query to get the difference in two tables with a common column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.One with original data (t1) and the other with altered data after some operation is performed (t2).  The structure of the two tables is same (Columns - GUID, ID, Value). GUID, ID form the Primary Key.

GUID and ID will remain same after the operation. However, some IDs (in t1) may be absent in t2 and some may be added in t2.
 Sample -

```
             t1                              t2
       GUID   ID   Value               GUID    ID   Value            
(i)     1      a     x                  1       a      x     --> same
(ii)    1      b     y                  1       b      w     --> VALUE different
(iii)   2      a     x                                       --> extra ID in t1
(iv)                                    2       b      z     --> extra ID in t2
```

My goal is to print the difference in t1 and t2 in the following format (new table)

```
                   Difference
         GUID    ID    Value1     Value2
   (ii)   1       b      y          w           --> VALUE different
   (iii)  2       a      x         NULL         --> extra ID in t1
   (iv)   2       b      NULL       z           --> extra ID in t2
```

My try -

I have split the problem into 3 parts.

1. Insert rows whose values are different

   ```
   INSERT INTO Difference(GUID,ID,Value1,Value2)
   SELECT t1.GUID, t1.ID, t1.Value, t2.Value from t1, t2
   WHERE t1.GUID = t2.GUID and t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Value != t2.Value
   ```

   The above query returns correct values.
2. Insert rows with IDs present in t1 and not present in t2.
   I want to use a query like this ->

   ```
   INSERT INTO Difference(GUID,ID,Value1)
   (SELECT t1.GUID, t1.ID, t1.Value from t1, t2 
        WHERE t1.GUID= t2.GUID and t1.ID IN 
              ((SELECT GUID,ID FROM t1 ) EXCEPT 
                 (SELECT GUID,ID FROM t2 ))) // I get an error here.
   ```

   Error :- Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

   I know I should select only "ID" column for IN clause. But that doesn't satisfy the condition. I want to use both GUID and ID in the 'IN' clause. I tried a number of other queries that didn't work. What should I do to get this result?
3. Same as 2nd with tables reversed.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long description. This is my first time using SQL. Let me know if I could have asked this question in a better way.

Comment: It's not bad as a first attempt. Essentially what you're after is a FULL OUTER JOIN, which MySQL doesn't support but, obviously can emulate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

you can union t1 joining t2 and t2 joining t1 and group by two columns key to allow only one record from their intersection

```
SELECT 
    x.GUID,
    x.ID,
    x.Value1,
    x.Value2
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.GUID, t1.ID, t1.Value AS Value1, t2.Value AS Value2 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.GUID = t1.GUID AND t2.ID = t1.ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.GUID, t2.ID, t1.Value AS Value1, t2.Value AS Value2  FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.GUID = t2.GUID AND t1.ID = t2.ID
  ) x
  GROUP BY x.GUID, x.ID;
```

Comment: I believe I can't use Select x.Value1 and x.Value2 since I haven't used them in the GROUP BY clause. And this query will also return the first row in my example right? I only want to select rows that are different - 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows.

Comment: I was able to run this query on my test data (it is database dependant - I use MariaDB). If you want only rows which are different add WHERE x.Value1 <> x.Value2 to the outer select.